# Find mix and max in sql from each partition

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min

I am trying to find min and max salaries for an employee along with the dept_id in the below case-

`Emp` table:

```
emp_id dept_id salary
----------------------
1         1     100
1         2     200
1         3     300
```

Desired output:

```
emp_id dept_id salary
---------------------
1         1     100
1         3     300
```

This is what I came up with, not sure if this is correct though-

```
select emp_id, dept_id, salary
from emp x
where salary in (select min(sal) 
                 from emp y 
                 where y.emp_id = x.emp_id)
   or salary in (select max(sal) 
                 from emp y 
                 where y.emp_id = x.emp_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *rows* with the minimum and maximum salaries, then one method uses window funtions:

```
select emp_id, dept_id, salary
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by salary asc) as seqnm_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by salary desc) as seqnm_desc
      from emp e
     ) e
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
select emp_id, dept_id, min(salary) as min_salary, max(salary) as max_salary
from Employees
group by emp_id
```

This query should do what you're requesting in a cleaner format by using [the "group by" clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) (this is the Oracle documentation, based on your tag).

Consider learning more about grouping sets.

Comment: IMHO group by has to have 2 columns as well; right ?

Comment: This query will fail, since there is no aggregate function used on dept_id. Also, the requirement here is to get 2 records for emp_id 1, one with min salary and the other with max salary, with the corresponding dept_id. See desired output.